# How to plot some particular data from a text file in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a two colum txt file and I plot the data as below

```
MyColor(n) = n==0 ? 0x008000  : n==1 ? 0xFF0000 : n==2 ? 0x000000 : 0xFF8C00
plot datafile u 1:2:(MyColor(column(-2))) w l  lw 1.0 lc rgb   var notitle
```

This gives me bottom three lines in three different colour and others in the same colour (`0xFF8C00`), Left figure. But I want to plot only upto `n==2` (there will be only three lines in the plot) and other row with `0xFF8C00` should not be in the plot and for each n `(n==0 ? 0x008000  : n==1 ? 0xFF0000 : n==2 ? 0x000000)` and I want to label a name with each colour as shown in right side figure.
[image]

Comment: Take a look at `help every` and `help label`.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. For simple file it worked well (help every) but for a file like , please download from here with replacing XXXX with https:// (XXXXwe.tl/t-5SFzfiKwjb  ) it is working on segments along X-axis.

Comment: the link is not valid anymore...

Comment: Yes, it was for seven days. I will update it. I am trapped in COVID-19 issue and can not work more. Thank you sir for your have a look on my post. I see your another reply that I will also update after some time.

Comment: I guess it's fine, I don't need the data anymore. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, I guess you are looking for `index` and `label`. Check `help index` and `help label`.
There might be a bit confusion about `every` and `index`.

- `every` allows selecting "blocks" which are separated by one empty line.
- `index` allows selecting "blocks" which are separated by two or more empty lines.

**Code:**

```
### plot only selected block
reset session

# create some test data
set print $Data
do for [i=1:7] {
    do for [j=1:100] {
        print sprintf("%.3f %.3f", j, sin(j/30.)+i*0.2 + 0.05*rand(0))
    }
    print ""; print ""    # two empty lines
}
set print

myColor(n) = n==0 ? 0x008000  : n==1 ? 0xFF0000 : n==2 ? 0x000000 : 0xFF8C00

set label 1 "LA" at 40, 1.3 tc rgb myColor(0)
set label 2 "ZA" at 30, 1.4 tc rgb myColor(1)
set label 3 "TA" at 67, 1.5 tc rgb myColor(2)

plot $Data u 1:2:(myColor(column(-2))) index 0:2 w l lw 1.0 lc rgb var notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]